# How to solve the warning given in Azure DevOps Build Pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I've been running the .NET Web App pipeline for couple of times where i observed the small warning coming again and again.

Not able to resolve this warning?

[image]

[image]

I tried editing the pipeline by adding the new task and running it, still getting the same warning.

Update:

CI Pipeline YAML:

> Can you share your current YAML Pipeline sample with us? –
> Kevin Lu-MSFT

```yaml
# ASP.NET Core (.NET Framework)
# Build and test ASP.NET Core projects targeting the full .NET Framework.
# Add steps that publish symbols, save build artifacts, and more:
# https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/dotnet-core

trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'

- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:DesktopBuildPackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)\WebApp.zip" /p:DeployIisAppPath="Default Web Site"'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    ArtifactName: 'drop'
    publishLocation: 'Container'


- task: WhiteSource@21
  inputs:
    cwd: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
    scanReportTimeout: '5'
```

> Please provide more information about the warning and the pipeline –
> Arko

- Pipeline is a Build of .NET 8 Web Application, updating the front end content and publishing to Azure Repos and then automatically build the app using the CI pipeline.
- Recently added WhiteSource integration.
- Pipeline is successful but only the warning is shown in the Interface.

> Also check if you have any scheduled pipeline runs configured on the pipeline in the user interface. – Scott Richards

There are no scheduled pipelines and also Continuous deployment is not enabled when the CI Pipeline runs.

Comment: Can you share your current YAML Pipeline sample with us?

Comment: Based on the given context, it is not clear what the warning is or what the pipeline is doing. Please provide more information about the warning and the pipeline

Comment: Also check if you have any scheduled pipeline runs configured on the pipeline in the user interface.

Comment: I have added information as per my knowledge. Let me know if any thing required. Thank you!

Comment: @Vamsi You can refer to my answer and check if it can work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your YAML sample, the triggers settings has no issues.

I can reproduce the same issue in one of my Pipelines.

[image]

To solve this issue, you can refer to the following steps:

Step1: Navigate to **Edit Yaml Pipeline -> Triggers -> YAML -> Get Sources -> Default branch for manual and scheduled builds**. Check if the current branch should be correct branch.

[image]

Step2: You can change the branch to another branch and save the Pipeline. Then you can change back to the original branch and save the Pipeline again.

Then you can run the Pipeline again and check if the error has disappeared.

The issue should come from the Azure DevOps Pipeline itself. I suggest that you can report the issue to the site: [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/AzureDevOps/report)

Azure DevOps developers will further investigate and resolve issues with Azure DevOps itself.

Here is the similar ticket: [Some recent issues detected related to pipeline trigger.](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Some-recent-issues-detected-related-to-p/1620293)

This issue has been solved before, but it seems to have reappeared recently.

Comment: I didn't used classic editor for modifying the branch as you shown. And If I see the branches in the YAML pipeline interface - except master branch, I don't have any other branch - https://i.imgur.com/3xQHVOz.png

Comment: main (Default) branch doesn't have any code to change. Even If I try to change, it is showing like https://i.imgur.com/aTN6JDA.png

Comment: @Vamsi Can you refer to the steps in the answer to change the **Default branch for manual and scheduled builds** in YAML Classic edit and then change back to master branch. For example: you can change to main branch and then change back to master branch. Then the error in Pipeline UI will disappear

Comment: I didn't create the pipeline using classic editor. How do I edit using classic edit? @KevinLu-MSFT and can you also check my 1st two comments

Comment: @Vamsi  Can you check if you can see the screenshot of the step 1 in the answer? When we use YAML Pipeline, it also has the classic edit. We can go to the classic edit var Trigger option.